# Question about the discrete symmetries of several fields

Tags: field-theory, cpt-symmetry

Short 4 questions:

1. Is free Klein-Gordon field possess some discrete symmetries? Is it invariant under $P$, $T$ separately?
2. Is free Proca field possess some discrete symmetries? Is it invariant under $C$, $P$, $T$ separately?
3. Is free Maxwell field possess some discrete symmetries? Is it invariant under $C$, $P$, $T$ separately?
4. For question 2&3, what will happen if them equipped with source, such as add a term $A_\mu J^\mu$ in Lagrangian density ($A_\mu$ for gauge field and $J^\mu$ for source current)?